# Full storage without reason and not working

Tags: boot, bash, monitor, storage

I have an Ubuntu OS in VMware, and Worked with it for about 3 months.
Although its disk had 100GB space for data, recently its performance became low and after rebooting the OS it's not working and showing me data before booting.
In my SYSTEM MONITOR SOFTWARE I Had 30GB, but my real storage is 100GB.

I tested <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for Login in and it works with Bash and is OK, but the UI and First Login Page is Not Loading.

OS load and mapping:

[image: Screen photo]

Comment: The disk space may be 100G, but the Ubuntu installer often leaves about half of that unused. Using commands like `df` and `du` will tell you if there is any space left in the filesystem. `lsblk` will show you the size of the disk available.